# Issues with Pymc3 Summary

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I am currently struggling to obtain a summary of the statistics of a model I ran through Bayesian regression on. I first used Lasso and model selection to filter the best variables, then used `pm.Model` to obtain the regression proper.

Of course, having 'filtered' the explanatory variables that weren't relevant, the shape of the X matrix had changed. The data I worked on is the load_boston dataset from sklearn.dataset. I coded the data as independent variable and the target as dependent variable.

Having performed model selection with `SelectFromModel`, I used the `get.support` method to obtain an index of the retained variables. I then used a loop over both the indexes of all variables and the numbers contained in the support, with the purpose of storing the names of the retained variables in an empty list I had created at hoc. The code looks something like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(9)

# Load the boston dataset.
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston = load_boston()
X, y = boston['data'], boston['target']

# Here is the code for the estimator LassoCV 

# Here is the code for Model Selection
support(indices=True) #to obtain the list of indices of retained variables
X_transform = sfm.transform(X) #to remove the unnecessary variables

#Here is the line for linear modeling

#I initialize some useful variables

m = y.shape[0]
n = X.shape[1]
c = supp.shape[0]

L = boston['feature_names']
varnames=[]


for i in range (0, n):
    for j in range (0, c):
        if i == supp[j]:
            varnames.append(L[i])          


 pm.summary(trace, varnames=varnames)
```

The console then displays 'KeyError: RM', which is one of the names of the variables used. One issue I noticed that every object of varnames is classified as `str_ object of numpy module`, meaning that I can't read the name of the retained variables on the list unless I double click on them.

How could I fix this? I have no clue what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you read this? http://docs.pymc.io/intro.html "Models are defined using a context manager (`with` statement). The model is specified declaratively inside the context manager, instantiating model variables and transforming them as necessary." Besides, this line `support(indices=True)` doesn't work